# Closing webkit window from ReactJS controlled dom element

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-webkit

I'm building an application using the ReactJS framework in node-webkit.  I have a close button that is controlled inside a React component.  After the page has to re-render (aka, a parent component has a state change), my window.close() call will fail with:

> Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

I'm guessing the React state change and/or render are somehow re-nesting my class inside some other file.

I have tried using jQuery's event system to route the window.close onto the html source file of the page using:

```
// this is directly on my index.html file
$(document).on( "cleanup", function(){
  window.close();
});
```

And

```
// this is in a function of my react componenet
$(document).trigger("cleanup");
```

This results in the same behaviour as calling `window.close()` directly on the onClick callback of my react dom element after a re-render.

I'm hesitant to tear up my react component just to nest my quit button in the source of the page, and would like other possible working suggestions.

Comment: Scripts don't change contexts unless you recompile functions which React never does.  Something else is going on.

Comment: Well, I was also under the impression, but my assumption is the only thing that makes even slight logical sense, since closing the window only breaks when React re-renders the page.